# En los textos antiguos, ¿era más largo el verbo "tenemos"? ¿Se originó "tenemos" a partir de dos palabras separadas?

Tags: verbos, orígenes

¿"tenemos" se escribía como "tener emos" en los viejos tiempos?

En el idioma inglés, la oración, "¿***Have we*** sufficient comestibles for the winter?" está fasionado de antiguo. "**Have we**" is similar a "tenemos". Sin embargo, muchas personas nacidas en América del Norte entienden oraciones donde el verbo se encuentra a la izquierda del pronombre.

Nunca he estudiado latín. Perdóname por no saber la raíz de las palabras en "tenemos"

Si no eliminamos ninguna letra (si expandimos la palabra), ¿cómo se vería la palabra grande y larga y cuál es una palabra en inglés para cada segmento?

Comment: We say edibles, not comestible in English. tenemos would normally be: do we have. Have we is somewhat more British and quite formal. I don't understand your point about the verb being to the left of the pronoun. You can't compares English questions to Spanish one. In Spanish, it's just intonation and punctuation, not structure.

Answer (score 1):

**¿"tenemos" se escribió como "tener emos" en los viejos tiempos?**

**La respuesta corta es no**. En español este tipo de formación evolucionó hacia el futuro imperfecto pues éste no deriva morfológicamente de la lengua latina sino que el español creo a partir de dos partículas su propio futuro imperfecto de indicativo, sirviéndose así tanto del infinitivo de presente como del presente de indicativo del verbo haber. Un ilustrativo ejemplo lo podemos encontrar en el verbo "amar" al igual que se conformaron los demás;

> **The short answer is no**. In Spanish, this type of formation evolved towards the imperfect future since it does not derive morphologically
> from the Latin language, but Spanish created its own future imperfect
> indicative from two particles, thus using both the present infinitive
> and the present indicative of the verb to have An illustrative example
> can be found in the verb "amar" (to love) just like the others;

Futuro Imperfecto de indicativo del verbo "amar"

- amar he - amaré
- amar has - amarás
- amar ha - amará
- **amar hemos - amaremos**
- amar habéis - amaréis
- amar han - amarán

---

La evolución semántica del verbo "**tener**" actual fue más compleja y aunque habría que hablar de algunos verbos relacionados, como el verbo "ser" o "hacer" y algunos aspectos etimológicos, simplemente resumiré que en la antigüedad era predominante el uso del verbo "**haber**" por el de "**tener**" así queda atestiguado en el "Poema del Mio Cid" y en las obras de Berceo, donde el uso del verbo "haber" como impersonal es escasísimo.

> The semantic evolution of the current verb "**tener**" was more
> complex and although it would be necessary to talk about some related
> verbs, such as the verb "to be" or "to do" and some etymological
> aspects, I will simply summarize that in ancient times the use of the
> verb "**haber**" (to have) for that of "**tener**" is thus attested in the
> "Poema del Mio Cid" and in the works of Berceo, where the use of the
> verb "to have" as impersonal is very scarce.

---

**Verbo "Haber" del lat. "habēre", "Tener".**

Ejemplos donde "**Haber**" es **igual** a "**Tener**"

- "Dios **haia** en su gloria" (Dios **tenga** es su gloria).

> God have in his glory.

- **Haya** por presentada la solicitud. (Tenga por presentada la solicitud).

> Consider the application submitted

- He **habido** cuatro mulas pardas y un caballo. (He tenido cuatro mulas pardas y un caballo).

> I have had four brown mules and a horse